# iis 404 error when removing hash tag from url angularjs app

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, angularjs-routing, hashtag

I'm developing a single page app using angularJS(client) and mvc web api (server). I have two physical page first Login.html and second Index.html 
when user successfully log in redirects to Index.html and other parts of my app load dynamically into div signed with `ng-view` inside Index.html page and I use AngularJS `$routeProvider`to  configure my routes with their associated templates and controllers. I recently removed hash tag from url using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and adding `<base href="/Index.html">` to head section of Index.html Page.I have a route that take a dynamic parameter like so `Index.html/MetaDetails/123456` when I go to such page for first time every thing is fine but when refresh the page I receive **iis 404 error**

here is my route configuration using `$routeProvider`

```
    App.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/Index.html', {
    templateUrl: 'View/HomePage.html'
})
    .when('/MetaDetails/:url', {
        templateUrl: 'View/MetaDetails/MetaDetails.html'
    }).when('/Logout', {
        templateUrl: 'View/Users/logout.html',
        controller: 'LogoutController'
    }).when('/MetaCRUD', {
        templateUrl: 'View/MetaDetails/MetaCRUD.html',
        typeTemplate:'insert',
        controller: 'MetaCRUDController'
    }).when('/MetaCRUD/:url', {
        templateUrl: 'View/MetaDetails/MetaCRUD.html',
        typeTemplate: 'update',
        controller: 'MetaCRUDController'
    }).when('/MetaReport', {
        templateUrl: 'View/Report/MasterReport.html',
        controller: 'reportController'
    })
     .when('/404', {
         templateUrl: 'View/ErrorPage.html',

     })
    .otherwise({

        redirectTo: '/404'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

});

I know it happens because it conflicts with iis routing and knows my route as a real physical page so most probable solution would be url rewriting I used following rewriting rule

```
<rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

**Update 2 :**

then when I refresh or redirect from an other url my route doesn't change but Index.html is shown without it's css an js refrences included (totally devastated) as if it has no css and js and it's basically because it tries to read resources from host/metadetails/example.css or host/metadetails/example.js instead of host/example.js
how does it happen and how can i make it get resources from root not /metadetals path

what do you think would be the appropriate solution(which probably would be an iis url rewriting) to solve this isue

note that it's very important to me to keep my single page structure on the other hand when I navigate from one page to another for example from metaCRUD (index.html/MetaCRUD) to desired MetaDetails(index.html/MetaDetails/someid)
I dont want my page being post back **at all** just like when I used to use hash tag which every thing was fine and only templates and data changed with no post back

**Update 3**

I just figure out that the problem arises only when my route has parameter (index.html/MetaDetails/someid)

how can I rewrite this url to make iis not mistakenly recognize my parameter included route as physical path???

any help would be appreciated

Comment: please give me some help I really need it

Comment: Hi Have you got any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

It's nice how everyone tells you how to remove the hashtag, but not the fix of the refresh.

Here's what worked for me:

1. app.js: add "$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);" in app.config as first line.
2. index.html: add "" in your  as the first line.
3. web.config: add the following at the end of your config:

```html
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
```

This worked for me. Apologies, the editor was a bit moody.